# Unable to register Microsoft.AppConfiguration in the 12-month free subscription

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-app-configuration

I got a 12-month free subscription which includes $200 credit. I'm unable to register `Microsoft.AppConfiguration`. Is it not included in the free subscription? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-services

> Error: creating Configuration Store (Subscription: "d06b4e1f-4bcd-40ea-87c4-c1ecf574a2df"
> │ Resource Group Name: "pr-euw-terraform-rg"
> │ Configuration Store Name: "pr-euw-appconfiguration"): performing Create: Put "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/d06b4e1f-4bcd-40ea-87c4-c1ecf574a2df/resourceGroups/pr-euw-terraform-rg/providers/Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/pr-euw-appconfiguration?api-version=2023-03-01": The Resource Provider was not registered
> │
> │ Resource Providers (APIs) in Azure need to be registered before they can be used - however the Resource
> │ Provider was not registered, and calling the API returned the following error:
> │
> │ The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.AppConfiguration'. See https://aka.ms/rps-not-found for how to register subscriptions. >
> │
> │ The Azure Provider by default will automatically register certain Resource Providers at launch-time,
> │ whilst it's possible to opt-out of this (which you may have done)
> │
> │ Please ensure that this Resource Provider is properly registered, you can do this using the Azure CLI
> │ for example to register the Resource Provider "Some.ResourceProvider" is registered run:
> │
> │ > az provider register --namespace "Some.ResourceProvider"
> │
> │ Resource Providers can take a while to register, you can check the status by running:
> │
> │ > az provider show --namespace "Some.ResourceProvider" --query "registrationState"
> │
> │ Once this outputs "Registered" the Resource Provider is available for use and you can re-run Terraform.
> │
> │
> │   with azurerm_app_configuration.appconfiguration,
> │   on main.tf line 79, in resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "appconfiguration":
> │   79: resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "appconfiguration" {

```
# Key Vault
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                        = "${var.name_prefix}-kv"
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = true

  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id          = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id          = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    key_permissions    = ["Get", "Create", "Delete", "List", "Restore", "Recover", "UnwrapKey", "WrapKey", "Purge", "Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Sign", "Verify", "GetRotationPolicy"]
    secret_permissions = ["Get", "Set"]
  }
}

output "tenant_id" {
    value = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
}

output "object_id" {
    value = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ai_connection_string" {
  name         = "ApplicationInsightsConnectionString"
  value        = "InstrumentationKey=${azurerm_application_insights.ai.instrumentation_key};IngestionEndpoint=https://westeurope-4.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westeurope.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}

# Azure App Configuration
resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "appconfiguration" {
  name                = "${var.name_prefix}-appconfiguration"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku                 = "standard"
}

resource "azurerm_app_configuration_key" "ai_connection_string" {
  configuration_store_id = azurerm_app_configuration.appconfiguration.id
  key                    = "ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"
  value                  = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${azurerm_key_vault_secret.ai_connection_string.id})"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the error message, you will see the following:

> The Resource Provider was not registered │ │ Resource Providers (APIs)
> in Azure need to be registered before they can be used - however the
> Resource │ Provider was not registered, and calling the API returned
> the following error: │ │ The subscription is not registered to use
> namespace 'Microsoft.AppConfiguration'

Before you can create an App Configuration resource in an Azure Subscription, that Subscription must be registered to with `Microsoft.AppConfiguration` resource provider.

Please see this link for instructions on how to register a Subscription with a resource provider: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types.

Once that is done successfully, you should not get the error you are getting.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried to do but look: https://i.imgur.com/yEXk9oP.png. Register is disabled

Comment: Did you search for Microsoft.AppConfiguration there? I believe the way UI works is that you select a resource provider and then `Register` or `Unregister` button gets enabled.

Comment: Oohh, thanks. I had to search for it first, then highlight it and then click on "Register"